# Trouble with Git repo in project via Composer..?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm working with Composer to pull in libraries, and I'm struggling with something.  Here is the composer.json that I'm working with:

```
{
  "require": {
    "mike182uk/paypal-ipn-listener": "~4.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/angelleye/filemakerapi.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run composer update it's pulling in the paypal-ipn-listener stuff, but it's not pulling in the filemakerapi stuff.

What's strange is the first time I ran it I did see that it went through all the different tags in the repo, and showed the versions (9.0, 10.0, 11.0, etc.) but then it ended up telling me "nothing to install or update."

Now when I run it I just get that same message that there is simply nothing to install or update.

I also tried this for the repositories part instead...

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/angelleye/filemakerapi"
    }
  ]
```

I get the same result with both of those methods, though.  I can't figure out why it won't actually pull in the master branch or a tagged version of that repo.

Any information on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a repository doesn't automatically pull in the code. It just tells composer where it should look to meet dependencies.

You will need to add a require entry for `matatirosoln/filemaker-api` (the package name in that repo's `composer.json`) in order for it to pull in that dependency.